# extjs 4 getLastSeletedCell in a grid

Tags: extjs, selection, cell

i worked on a grid in extjs 4 and i want to show an editor if someone has ben clicked to times on the same cell.
now i have the problem that i cant find a method like grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSeletedCell() to check in a beforechange event if the last selected cell has been changed.

i tried grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition() and getSelection but both returns null
only grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected() returns the record but in this case i can only check the row and not the column which was selected.
does have anyone an idea how to check if someone has ben clicked to times on the same cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i feel, selected cell can be found using below way while using cellSelectionModel with grid.

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCell();
```

You need to store the selected some how to perform your operation.